# Create and Input Structure Array from a Function

Tags: c, struct

I have a function, it will allocate a struct pointer from main function into a struct array and using scanf i want to input data into struct.

This is the struct:

```
struct contact
{
    int id;
};
```

and this is the function.

```
int add(struct contact **etc)
{
    int no, i;
    printf("How many?\n");
    scanf("%d", &no);
    *etc = (struct contact*) malloc(no * sizeof(struct contact));
    for(i = 0; i < no; i++)
    {
        printf("Id of student %d, in order\n", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &(etc[i]->id));
    }

    return no;
}
```

and related codes of main function

```
struct contact *etc;
int no;
no = add(&etc);
```

However, after first input it seems i am trying to access an non-allocated area.But i allocated area.I think the problem is addressing of structure array, but i am not sure.

Thanks.

Comment: `scanf("%d", &(etc[i]->id));` --> `scanf("%d", &(*etc)[i].id);`

Comment: Yup, like i guess, thanks, should have asked instead of trying and searching.